# How to cast a list to all the unique value of a dataframe column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame here say with column A and B, and I have a `list = [[0.1,0.2] ,[0.3,0.4], [0.8,0.6], [0.1,0.65]]`

```
DataFrame
          A
0         5  
1         5
2         5
3         8
4         8
5         9 
6         9
7         10
8         10
```

I want to create a separate column B and cast each element (list) of the above list for all the unique values in column A i.e. I want to achieve the following

```
DataFrame

         A            B
0         5        [0.1,0.2]
1         5        [0.1,0.2]
2         5        [0.1,0.2]
3         8        [0.3,0.4]
4         8        [0.3,0.4]
5         9        [0.8,0.6]
6         9        [0.8,0.6]
7         10       [0.1,0.65]
8         10       [0.1,0.65]
```

Is there a way to do this in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use numpy indexing with convert column `A` by [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) for encoding values to enumerated array, solution working only if number of unique values of `A` column is same or less like length of list:

```
L = [[0.1,0.2] ,[0.3,0.4], [0.8,0.6], [0.1,0.65]]

df['B'] = np.array(L)[pd.factorize(df['A'])[0]].tolist()
print (df)
    A            B
0   5   [0.1, 0.2]
1   5   [0.1, 0.2]
2   5   [0.1, 0.2]
3   8   [0.3, 0.4]
4   8   [0.3, 0.4]
5   9   [0.8, 0.6]
6   9   [0.8, 0.6]
7  10  [0.1, 0.65]
8  10  [0.1, 0.65]
```

**Detail**:

```
print (pd.factorize(df['A'])[0])
[0 0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3]
```

Another idea working for any data, if not match get missing values for last rows with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['B'] = pd.factorize(df['A'])[0]
df['B'] = df['B'].map(dict(enumerate(L)))
```

Or:

```
#only 3 values
L = [[0.1,0.2] ,[0.3,0.4], [0.8,0.6]]

df['B'] = df['A'].map(dict(zip(df['A'].unique(), L)))
print (df)
    A           B
0   5  [0.1, 0.2]
1   5  [0.1, 0.2]
2   5  [0.1, 0.2]
3   8  [0.3, 0.4]
4   8  [0.3, 0.4]
5   9  [0.8, 0.6]
6   9  [0.8, 0.6]
7  10         NaN
8  10         NaN
```

If want repalce missing values by empty list or some another value is possible use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
L = [[0.1,0.2] ,[0.3,0.4], [0.8,0.6]]

from  itertools import zip_longest

df['B'] = df['A'].map(dict(zip_longest(df['A'].unique(), L, fillvalue=[0,0])))
print (df)
    A           B
0   5  [0.1, 0.2]
1   5  [0.1, 0.2]
2   5  [0.1, 0.2]
3   8  [0.3, 0.4]
4   8  [0.3, 0.4]
5   9  [0.8, 0.6]
6   9  [0.8, 0.6]
7  10      [0, 0]
8  10      [0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can create a dictionary of the unique values in column `A` mapped to the list. Then we use `Series.map` to create our new column:

```
df['B'] = df['A'].map({a: l for a, l in zip(df['A'].unique(), lst)})

    A            B
0   5   [0.1, 0.2]
1   5   [0.1, 0.2]
2   5   [0.1, 0.2]
3   8   [0.3, 0.4]
4   8   [0.3, 0.4]
5   9   [0.8, 0.6]
6   9   [0.8, 0.6]
7  10  [0.1, 0.65]
8  10  [0.1, 0.65]
```